# How do you easily copy a block from the terrain into your inventory in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was watching some Grian videos and I saw in one of his videos he sort of copies a block and it puts the block into his hand instantly. How exactly does he do this? (by the way he is in creative and he also is not in his inventory).

Comment: Can you link the video here so we can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're in creative mode you can middle-click to copy the block you're currently looking at. You have to be close enough to the block that you could interact with it, and it creates a copy of the block type rather than a true copy (copying a chest doesn't copy the contents of the chest).

You can also do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Middle click to copy contents of container objects. This includes chests, dispensers, hoppers, command blocks and others.

You can also do it in survival mode, but rather than creating a copy of the block it will just take it from your inventory instead (as long as you're actually carrying that type of block).

Comment: Don't use the Middle click, use the PICK BLOCK button with CTRL

Comment: @RookieTEC9 I don't think that that's the default key combination.

Comment: No I mean use the PICK BLOCK button to be more specific since middle click is only the default so it may be a bit confusing